# navigationItem.prompt & UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, prompt, uinavigationitem

Is it possible to make calls to navigationItem on a UIImagePickerController? Specifically, the image picker? Below I've linked an image of what I'm trying to achieve ( screen shot taken from another app doing the same thing). Once the user selects an image from the picker the navigationItem.prompt is set and, though I think it might be a HIG violation, the right bar button is changed from the standard cancel button. I can set the prompt on a "normal" view no problem with:

`self.navigationItem.prompt = myString;`

But this does not seem to work when I try to use it in the context of a picker with:

```
myPicker.navigationItem.prompt = myString;
```

I've tried using it when the picker is created and also in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: which is really where I need to set it as I'm letting the user select multiple images instead of dismissing the picker as soon as one image is selected. Nothing seems to work.

Here's a image of the desired behavior:

http://i51.photobucket.com/albums/f353/zoso5th/after.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone answered this for me on the Apple dev forums:

```
UINavigationBar *bar = picker.navigationBar;
UINavigationItem *navItem = bar.topItem;
navItem.prompt = @"Some new prompt";
```

I wasn't correctly accessing the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

**Someone answered this for me on the Apple dev forums:
UINavigationBar *bar = picker.navigationBar;
UINavigationItem *navItem = bar.topItem;
navItem.prompt = @"Some new prompt";
I wasn't correctly accessing the navbar.**

Use the code after calling 'presentModalViewController'.....like below...

**[controller presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];**

UINavigationBar *bar = picker.navigationBar;
UINavigationItem *navItem = bar.topItem;
navItem.prompt = @"Some new prompt";